# Share file from phone with PC using wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my application i have to share files in SD card of phone with PC using WiFi.I searched but cant find a solution for this.Please help me?

Comment: You'll need to have a client on the PC. Eithor use FTP or SMB.

Comment: Is there a way to make phone as server and browse and download file in phone from PC

Comment: You need to see these links: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882772/android-server-pc-client

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851013/how-to-get-simple-android-client-and-pc-server-get-working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182477/a-simple-client-server-androidpc